# How to run a block of code after each @test, no matter if the test is @Disabled or not?

Tags: java, junit5, extent

Basically I would like to add an entry to my Extent report for "Skipped Tests". I understand I can use @AfterEach, however I see that the @AfterEach code block does not get executed for @Disabled Test in Junit5.

I tried using TestWatcher interface and overrided the method testDisabled like below:

```
package utils;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.TestWatcher;


public class MyTestWatcher implements TestWatcher {
                public static String testStatus;
                public static String testCaseName;
    @Override
    public void testAborted(ExtensionContext Context, Throwable throwable) {
                testStatus = "Aborted";
                testCaseName = Context.getDisplayName();
                System.out.println("Test Aborted: " + Context.getDisplayName());
                }

    @Override
    public void testDisabled(ExtensionContext Context, Optional<String> optional) {
                testStatus = "Skipped";
                testCaseName = Context.getDisplayName();  
                System.out.println("Test Skipped: " + Context.getDisplayName());
                }

    @Override
    public void testFailed(ExtensionContext Context, Throwable throwable) {
                testStatus = "Failed";
                testCaseName = Context.getDisplayName();   
               System.out.println("Test Failed: " + Context.getDisplayName());
}

    @Override
    public void testSuccessful(ExtensionContext Context) {
                testStatus = "Passed";
                testCaseName = Context.getDisplayName();
                System.out.println("Test Passed: " + Context.getDisplayName());
    }

}
```

Based on the 'testStatus' and 'testCaseName' variables, which are set in the testDisabled() method above, I would like to run a block of code from my test class, to add an entry to my Extent report saying which test case was skipped.

Comment: Run the non-skipped tests. and the process all Skipped annotations separately. Merge the documentation. This is the only non-hacking way, as there probably is no provision for not handling a test, but then still handle it a bit.

Comment: so what is your question? `TestWatcher` approach didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly you just need to apply `TestWatcher` to your test to solve your problem. With **JUnit 5** you can use `@ExtendsWith` *annotation*. Complete example will be:

```
@ExtendWith(MyTestWatcher.class)
class MyTest {

  @Test
  void test() {
    System.out.println("inside active test");
  }

  @Test
  @Disabled
  void testDisabled() {
    System.out.println("inside disabled test");
  }

}
```

With output:

```
inside active test
Test Passed: test()
Test Skipped: testDisabled()
```

> Tested with **JUnit 5.4.2**

Comment: My question is, I had to add the "Skipped tests" to my extent report. I add the test report steps in AfterEach block. However for Disabled test in Junit5, the AfterEach block doesn't get executed. So I was not able to add the 'Skipped Test' info to the report.

Comment: using your watcher and my code abobe you should be able to achieve it

Comment: seems that your question is more relates to the ExtentReport instantiation and not to `@AfterEach`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add reporting for Skipped Tests by initializing the Extent Report from the MyTestWatcher class. Even though the ExtentReport object was already initialized in my test class, when I again try to initialize (which would end up creating another HTML file report), I added the below code to my ExtentManager class:

```
public static ExtentReports GetExtent(String env){
        **if (extent != null)
          return extent; //avoid creating new instance of html file**
        extent = new ExtentReports();       
        extent.attachReporter(getHtmlReporter());
        extent.setSystemInfo("Environment",env);
        extent.setAnalysisStrategy(AnalysisStrategy.SUITE);
        return extent;
```

And my updated code in MyTestWatcher class looks like below:

```
package utils;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.TestWatcher;

import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.Status;




public class MyTestWatcher implements TestWatcher {
                public static String testCaseName;
                public static ExtentReports extent;
                public static ExtentTest report;

    static 
                {
                extent = utils.ExtentReportManager.GetExtent(System.getProperty("env"));
                report = extent.createTest("Skipped Tests", "Tests which are skipped are displayed here.");
                }
    @Override
    public void testAborted(ExtensionContext Context, Throwable throwable) {
                testCaseName = Context.getDisplayName();
                System.out.println("Test Aborted: " + Context.getDisplayName());
                }

    @Override
    public void testDisabled(ExtensionContext Context, Optional<String> optional) {
                testCaseName = Context.getDisplayName();  
                System.out.println("Test Skipped: " + Context.getDisplayName());
                report.createNode(testCaseName).log(Status.SKIP, "This test is marked as @DISABLED");
                }

    @Override
    public void testFailed(ExtensionContext Context, Throwable throwable) {
                testCaseName = Context.getDisplayName();   
               System.out.println("Test Failed: " + Context.getDisplayName());
                }

    @Override
    public void testSuccessful(ExtensionContext Context) {
                testCaseName = Context.getDisplayName();
                System.out.println("Test Passed: " + Context.getDisplayName());
    }

}
```